# Jquery Add Event To Star rating

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce default star rating and i have assigned this jquery to the stars html.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $(".comment-form-rating .stars span a").click(function() {
      alert("test"); 
      $(this).parents("form:first").submit();

      });

    });

</script>
```

Html:

```
<p class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">Rating</label>
  <p class="stars">
    <span>
      <a class="star-1" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="star-2" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="star-3" href="#">3</a>
      <a class="star-4 active" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="star-5" href="#">5</a>
    </span>
  </p>
  <select name="rating" id="rating" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Rate…</option>
    <option value="5">Perfect</option>
    <option value="4">Good</option>
    <option value="3">Average</option>
    <option value="2">Not that bad</option>
    <option value="1">Very Poor</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

Clicking the stars and no response?  I don't see any errors in firebug... no alert.  I want the user to click on a star and then their rating is submitted.  The star rating system work with jQuery also so they might be conflict but how do i get my code to work?  A submit button would work but my boss doesn't want that..

How do i solve this so my code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the way it's looking for the elements to 'watch' and it's working great.

```
$(function() {
  $('.stars').find('a').click(function() {
      alert("test"); 
      $(this).parents("form:first").submit();
  });
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uosab7o4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your event looks correct, but you've probably forgotten to put it inside `$(document).ready(function() { // your code });`.